# how to fit entire width of a compoent

Tags: zk

I am new to ZK frame work. I wanted to have a layout where one Window should fit the 
enitre width of div component. I tried to add width=100% but it does not work.
 how do I do that? Please see the code below

```
<zk>
<div style="background:yellow;">
    <hlayout sclass="z-valign-top" style="background:red;">    

        <window width="100%" title="win" border="normal"/>
    </hlayout>
    <separator/>   
    </div> 
</zk>
```

Comment: first hlayout must fit the div and as window is inside hlayout you are here just makingwindow to fit the hlayout width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using relative sizes (percent) are by my experience often counter-productive. Use [hflex/vflex](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Hflex_and_Vflex) instead.

```
<zk>
<div style="background:yellow;">
    <hlayout sclass="z-valign-top" style="background:red;">    
        <window hflex="1" title="win" border="normal"/>
    </hlayout>
    <separator/>   
    </div> 
</zk>
```